# Which video file formats can QTKit play?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video, qtkit

Is there an overview of file formats which QTKit understands?

Answer (score 4):

You use QTMovie's +movieFileTypes: method choosing a type option from:

```
QTIncludeStillImageTypes
QTIncludeTranslatableTypes
QTIncludeAggressiveTypes
QTIncludeCommonTypes
QTIncludeAllTypes
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the programmatic QTMovie +movieFileTypes, Bob mentions, you can also check the Quicktime Player Spec page:

http://www.apple.com/quicktime/player/specs.html